DBT is unable to find stored manifest file in Azure Pipeline
I am developing a CI/CD pipeline using Azure Pipelines that should perform Slim CI. The database is Snowflake and the transformation tool is dbt.
When running the code locally, everything works as expected. I have changed a model called model_test_4 since the last run, and it successfully identifies that it should clone its predecessor and only build model_test_4. However, when I run it in an Azure Pipeline, I encounter the following issue:

Unable to do partial parsing because saved manifest not found.
Starting full parse.

I have verified that the manifest file is loaded into the Ubuntu server. When I print the file located at dbt_project/dbt_manifest_temp_dir, the temporary directory exists, and the manifest.json file is present with all relevant data.
I am not sure what is going wrong and I can't figure out how to debug it.
Here are the commands I am running:
To find all models that have changed since the last run, I use:

dbt ls --select state:modified+ --state manifest_path --resource-type
model --output name

Using the above, I can clone all predecessors and then run only the models that has been changed:

dbt build --select state:modified+ --state manifest_path --target
cicd_target

As mentioned, this works as expected when running locally, but in the Azure Pipeline, the manifest file is not found.
Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Is the dbt build command performed in a different stage of your azure pipeline or as a step of the same stage?

They are all in the same stage I think. I just have a -steps block, where I 1) specify the python version to be used, 2) install uv which I use for dependency management instead of pip, 3) run a script that retrieves the manifest and puts it into a folder in my dbt_project, 4) runs the last script that performs slim CI using the manifest file.
